# Problems with launching GMaps in ZF2

Tags: php, google-maps, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use this module, https://github.com/gowsram/zf2-google-maps- , but I'm running into a problem.

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for GMaps\Service\GoogleMap
```

I have followed the instruction in the github readme, and have **downloaded zip file** and **unzipped** it into my **vendors** directory.

From what I understand, the line which calls the `ServiceLocator`,

```
$map = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('GMaps\Service\GoogleMap');
```

isn't pointing to the right place. Unfortunately my knowledge of how the service locator works isn't deep enough to figure out how to fix the problem, despite attempts to remedy this by diving into the docs. It's all a little over my head.

Do you have other tools that could work?
I need to get the Latitude and Longitude when I click on a point in the map.
But it would not launch .. .

If I put the following in config/application.config.php file:

```
<?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Auth',
        'Application',
        'User',
        'GMaps',
    ),
```

I get the following exceptions on the page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (GMaps) could not be initialized.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the module first to pair and use in application after cloning into the vendor.

In your `config/application.config.php` file of your project, add `GMaps` module like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'GMaps',
    ),
    // ...
);
```